# naming the tables in a multipart from statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query where I have 3 table variables of independent identifiers.  I want to cross join them to match up each combination from another table.

This runs fine

```
select i.*, d.*
  from @ids as i, @dates as d, @values as v
```

But when I run

```
select i.*, d.*
  from @ids as i, @dates as d, @values as v
  join other_table as ot with (nolock)
    on i.id_ = ot.someid
   and d.date_ = ot.somedate
   and v.item_ = ot.someitem
```

Only the last table `v` is recognized and I get

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10084
The multi-part identifier "d.date_" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10085
The multi-part identifier "v.item_" could not be bound.
```

What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple rule.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, you want `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select i.*, d.*
from @ids i cross join
     @dates d cross join
     @values v join
     other_tabl ot
     on i.id_ = ot.someid and
        d.date_ = ot.somedate snf
        v.item_ = ot.someitem;
```

A comma is not exactly the same as `CROSS JOIN`.  In addition to generating a Cartesian product of the rows in the tables, it also has scoping implications.  Basically, the comma *separates* the name spaces in the `FROM` clause.  So, the tables/aliases defined before the comma are not available afterwards.  (Of course, they are available in other clauses in the query such as `WHERE`.)